# Adding a post to google blogger with R httr

Tags: r, json, httr

I want to post a message to the Google blogger API with R, but I am puzzled how to format the request with R, httr and jsonlite. GET works, but the formatting of the POST message and the JSON isn't clear to me.

The example of a POST is shown at the Google developer page:

```
    POST https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8070105920543249955/posts/
    Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */
    Content-Type: application/json
{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "8070105920543249955"
  },
  "title": "A new post",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}
```

Creating the message:

```
amesg <- list(
  kind = "blogger#post", 
  blog =list(id = "..."), 
  Title = "A new post", 
  content = "With exciting content...")
jsnmesge <- jsonlite::toJSON(amesg,pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
httr::POST("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/.../posts/key=...", 
  body = jsnmesge)
```

Gives as response:

```
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;p...
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
```

Comment: Why do you have `key=...` in the URL When that doesn't seem to be in the example? For the authortization header, use `add_headers(Authorization="<your OAuth key>")` inside the `POST` call. Also you don't have to call `jsonlite::toJSON` yourself. You can pass the list object to `body=` and use `encode = "json"`

Comment: Thank you, it gets me a step further, but I still get <BR><title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title> and<BR><p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>

Comment: Are you sure you as using a valid id? Have you tried any other endpoints from the API?

Comment: The GET works fine, but I guess it has something to do with the formatting of the POST message in R (JSON part). I will take an extra look at it this weekend.